# How could I load the files of a directory 1 by 1 in C#?

Tags: c#, file-io

I want to load all xml files 1 by 1 by using C#. And all files are under same directory. 
Could you please give me some samples for it?

Thanks
SuT

Comment: Is it just one directory, or is it recursive? e.g. when there is another directory in the folder, should it search that too for files (and so forth)?

Comment: Did you try? Show me your implementation.

Comment: He said all files under the same directory.

Comment: What do you mean by 'loading'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just typing this from memory, but this would do the trick I believe:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(PathToYourFolder);

foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.xml")) 
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(fi.FullName);
}
```

If you do need to go into child folders then make this change:

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

Comment: I like this answer better than mine :) If this is what the author was looking for, this suits it more because of directly accessing the content as XmlDocument.

Comment: If you are in .Net 4.0, it's better to use EnumerateFiles instead of GetFiles method, to not load all files in memory at once. EnumerateFiles returns IEnumerable<FileInfo> instead on an array.

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure what you mean with "1 by 1" but i guess this is what you are looking for.

```
var xmls = Directory.GetFiles(myPath, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in xmls )
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

`xmls` are all files in `myPath` and also inside all subfolders via SearchOption you can define if you want all files or only TopLevel files. Next a fileStream is openend for eaech of the found files and a stream reader is used to read the whole content.